# Angular Sticky Sidebar

Tags: angular, angular-material, sidebar, sticky

I am strugling to have a sticky sidebar that stops scrolling when its bottom edge is reached, I would like to have similar effect the second example "Scrollable Sticky Element" on this page: https://abouolia.github.io/sticky-sidebar/#examples.

When the user reaches to the bottom of the sidebar, the bottom edge should stay stuck to the bottom of the browser window. However I want to archive this without JQuery (sticky-sidebar uses jQuery). Using just Angular.

Comment: do you use bootstrap ? if so, use [sticky-top](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/position/#sticky-top)

Comment: No, I am using Angular Material